# Android : Setting text and multiple images on top of image not working properly.

Tags: java, android, android-framelayout

I am working on an Android application in which I have an image of section which I am setting in a static manner. Now, for trying out, I am using GridView inside a framelayout. But when I do that, I am not able to see alphabets properly as I think they are going out of view-screen and the text of the section is no longer visible. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be nice.

activity_group_section.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sectionimage"
            android:layout_width="386dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sectionbackground"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sectionname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textView"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="3"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

SectionLazyAdapter.java :

```
public class SectionLazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;


    GridView gridView;

    static final String[] numbers = new String[] {
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};


    public SectionLazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_group_section, null);

        TextView sectionName = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.sectionname); // title
        GridView gridView = (GridView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        HashMap<String, String> sectionList = new HashMap<String, String>();
        sectionList = data.get(position);

        sectionName.setText(sectionList.get(GroupSectionActivity.msectionname));

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });

         return vi;
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of how it is looking, I would like to see the alphabets inside the image and name of section below the image, but that's not what is happening and the image is going outside as well.

[image: Screenshot]

I presume this is the problem with wrong configuration in XML file. Any help would be nice.

Comment: You shouldn't use `fill_parent` anymore, it's been deprecated.  Use `match_parent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that you are trying to put a GridView inside a ListView.
As I see you do this because you want a Sectioned GridView, I recommend just using a library that does that, like [this one](http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/). Google "gridview with sections" if you're not happy with it, you'll find plenty of other libraries and SO questions (I used the one in the link and was happy with it).

Now regarding why your approach is not working. There are a number of reasons that you will have a hard time going with this approach.

- ListViews don't cope well with other scrollable components (either as parent or as child).
- ListViews give children all the height they want, much like a ScrollView does with it's child. GridView is not ready for this, you need to force a certain height for it.
- Having an AdapterView inside an *infinite* view makes the View render *all* it's children. This makes the whole point of recycling views pointless

You can try and continue on this path, but I'm afraid Android will work against you.

Comment: I will start looking into it. Can you please give me an example how I can achieve the same with library, I am new to Android and especially UI programming and this thing is driving me nuts.

Comment: I see they offer an [example here](https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders/tree/master/Example). I also see that the library I gave you is discontinued. It's replaced by a better one that uses RecyclerView, [here](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM) - this one also [has examples](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM/tree/early_release_4/example). I won't edit my answer since the original library is a direct replacement for GridView, but I strongly recommend you use the [newer one](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM)

Answer (score 1):

The frame layout is useless so you should get rid of it.

Add this line to section name textview:

```
android:layout_below="@id/sectionimage"
```

PS: putting a scrollable view inside another scrollable view is not recommended as you'd have trouble scrolling.

Comment: Which layout should I use so that contents of gridview are displayed inside the sectionimage?

Comment: What about NestedScrollView?